# Make Firestore Requests at App Startup and save it (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a few Firestore requests on Flutter App Startup window and save the data inside a variable or something. Then I want to use this data across the App.

My app has many user data requests and I don't want to make them again and again in the app and save latency and cost. Is this possible/useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course you can do it, I used the same method in one personal project.

I dont really know what the question is but you can just download all the data you need in a FutureBuilder and then pass them further.

For this [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) would be helpfull but it is bit complex to understand at first but saves a bit more boilerplate code.